# How do I suppress an unwanted 'return' character after very simple AHK (AutoHotKeymacro?

Tags: autohotkey

I redefined all the keys on my numeric keypad to automate programming tasks, including 'cut, 'paste' and 'copy'.   Everything works apart from this macro (paste):

```
;=====  NumpadDot or  NumpadDel paste 
NumpadDot::
NumpadDel::
  Send,^v
Return
```

Surprisingly this sends a control-v - **Followed (slightly later) by a return/enter key.**  What causes AHK to send an extra keystroke and how do I prevent it?  – None of my other macros appear to have this problem.

Answer (score -1):

AHK probably interprets the `Return` as part of the Send command. Hotkeys automatically return, anyways, so you can just write:

```
NumpadDot::Send, ^v
NumpadDel::Send, ^v
```

...since it will 'Send' only the `^v` and return to your script.

Comment: `Return` does not get interpreted that way unless it's in braces `{}`. Additionally, it won't be part of the `Send` command if on its own line. Furthermore, this question was asked twice, perhaps mistakenly, with the actual answer from the OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58395525/how-do-i-suppress-an-unwanted-return-character-after-very-simple-ahk-autohotk