# How do I suppress an unwanted 'return' character after very simple AHK (AutoHotKey) macro?

Tags: autohotkey

I've redefined all the keys on the numeric keypad to automate programming tasks, including 'cut, 'paste' and 'copy'.   But this macro ('paste') fails:

```
;=====  NumpadDot or  NumpadDel paste 
NumpadDot::
NumpadDel::
  Send,^v
Return
```

Surprisingly this sends a control-v  **but followed (slightly later) by a 'return/enter' keystroke.**  What causes AHK to send an extra keystroke and **how do I prevent it**?  – None of my other macros have any problems.

Comment: I was not able to replicate the issue you experience with the code provided. Is it possible that you've copied something that has a return character at the end?

Comment: If only that were true. No it copies, pauses about 1/10 sec, then sends the return/enter.

Answer (score 0):

Finally discover the issue.  I had comments before each macro like this:

```
;=====  NumpadPgDn  3 / NumpadPgDn  paste 
Numpad3::
NumpadPgDn::
SetKeyDelay (150)
 Send,^v
Return
;===== Numpad0 / NumpadIns  to Copy
Numpad0::
NumpadIns::
  Send,^c
Return
```

Unfortunately in one of the comments I had a ':' (colon) in place of a ';' (semicolon). This alters the behavior of the ***preceding*** macro in the file and adds a enter keystroke after its execution.